# Sandbox: Localize listInstance title

Tags: sandbox-solution, localization, resource-files

how to localize listInstance title in sandboxed solution?

It is posible to add Resources.resx file to feature and localize ListDefinition:

```
<ListTemplate
        Name="TagsListDefinition"
        Type="20020"
        BaseType="0"
        OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
        SecurityBits="11"
        Sequence="410"
        DisplayName="$Resources:TagsListDefinitionDisplayName"
        Description="$Resources:TagsListDefinitionDescription"
        Category="Communications"
        Image="/_layouts/images/itgen.png"/>
```

But this don't work for ListInstance

```
<ListInstance Title="$Resources:TagsListInstanceTitle"
                OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
                TemplateType="20020"
                Url="Lists/Tags"
                Description="descr" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your format to pick the name from the Resource file is:

```
Name="$Resources:MyResources,TagsListInstanceTitle"
MyResources – name of the resources file (as described below)
TagsListInstanceTitle – the resource entry
```

And the name of Resources file (for the entry above) for English should be:

```
MyResources.en-US.resx
```

And deployed to:

```
{SharePointRoot aka 14 hive}Resources
```

**For SandBox solutions:**

You need to use Embedded Resource files. An Embedded Resource is compiled directly into the output assembly. [See the link about the their usage](http://blog.sharepointbits.com/2011/03/localization-in-sharepoint-2010-sandbox.html)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Falak, thanks. Your solution dosn't work in sandboxed solutions.

Comment: you need to use Embedded Resource files see my updated response.

Comment: Embedded Resource don't work in this scenario. Do you test it?